# Finding almost equal tuple members of two arrays?

Tags: python, position, tuples, uncertainty

I have 2 lists of positional tuples (x,y data).  I would like to return 2 arrays or lists of the indexes for positions (or a tuple) that are in both lists. However the positional data values will not be exactly equal, there will be an uncertianty of +/- 4 on both the x and y coordinates.

For example:

```
A=[(1168.593,9.874), (1799.244,40.201),(780.533,12.636)]
B=[(1170.909,8.194), (793.149,10.885), (1801.493,41.603)]
```

it should return:

```
c=[(0,0),(1,2)]
```

or:

```
d=[0,1] #indexes for A
e=[0,2] #indexes for B
```

Either one would be fine to use.

Is there a function in Python you can use that returns the indexes of matching data in 2 lists, by specifying a +/- value as well?

I need to do this for 3 lists of ~400 tuples each, which are not equal in size.

I was thinking of even using something like:

```
common=[a in A for a in B]
```

and somehow specifying a range for `a`, just looking at the x and y data and return the indices instead of true/false, but I really don't know how to approach this. Is a loop the only way to do this, by looking at each value separately, getting a difference between them and seeing if this is < 4, then getting the indexes?

Comment: When you say array, do you mean `list`?

Comment: But, there is no built-in functionality like you've described.

Comment: list or array, I updated the original post

Comment: ... so, a `numpy` array would be fine? or an `array.array`? Or do you actually mean `list` or `tuple`?

Comment: numpy would be preferable, by any sort of collection of indexes would be fine.  The returned format is not so critical, just that i have the indexes of both A and B lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a brute-force solution?

```
In [5]: c = []

In [6]: for i, (x1, y1) in enumerate(A):
   ...:     for j, (x2, y2) in enumerate(B):
   ...:         if (x1 - 4 <= x2 <= x1 + 4) and (y1 - 4 <= y2 <= y1 + 4):
   ...:             c.append((i,j))
   ...:
   ...:

In [7]: c
Out[7]: [(0, 0), (1, 2)]
```

Of course, you can replace the conditional with whatever you want. Likely, using `math.isclose` is a good idea. There may be a better `numpy` way of doing this in a vectorized fashion. But this should work if efficiency isn't a concern.

Comment: This maybe the way I'll have to go.  I was trying to avoid looping.... but I also cant see another way.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @gline given the scope of the problem you described, I don't think it will be an issue.

Comment: It turns out it is actually a dictionary of tuples that I am using, when I try and use this code specifying e.g. A[0] instead of A I get error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: Wait, you have a dictionary of ints? let me guess, the keys are `0, 1, 2...`? Why don't you just put that in a `list`?

Comment: Ok I've tried a few ways but I cannot get it to work.  I have now converted the data to a list of tuples, but I get the same error.  The list contains 3 indexes of type "tuple" e.g. A,B,C, inside each of these is 2 indexes of type float e.g. x,y data.  How do I index this correctly for enumerate?

Comment: after a bit of playing around with formatting the data individually into lists I got this to work thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can consider using function `isclose` from `math` module ?

Comment: From what I can see, this checks the 2 arrrays in full?

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will definitely use this in the future

Comment: Sure! My pleasure!